# ngFor without data binding

Tags: angular, data-binding, ngfor

How do I use the `*ngFor` directive without any data binding?

Besides the initial rendering, I don't want any changes to the model to be reflected in the view and I don't want any changes in the view to be reflected in the model.

#### Example

```
@Component({
  template: '<p *ngFor="let character of characters">{{ character }}</p>',
})
export class TestComponent {
  public characters = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
}
```

If I push an additional character onto the `characters` array it will render in the template.

I don't want this. I only want it to render once (with the first 3 characters) and any modification should not cause any changes in the view.

Comment: do you mean you want a "one time" binding ? I don't understand your question, can you give more informations about your goal ?

Comment: Just assign the initial retrieved value to a different variable and loop over that variable..

Comment: @Moug I have updated my question

Comment: @AshishRanjan 's answer is the simpliest, otherwise if you want this behaviour on all your component you can set your changeDetection to "OnPush",  and the binding refresh only if reference to object change , not value :

changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush

Comment: @Moug: Yeah, right! If Danyg is going to use OnPush change detection strategy, then his component is very very specific. View will not detect changes for any of the variables unless references are changed. This will also affect any other components used inside this component.

Answer (score 1):

As far as not reflecting any change in model to the the view after initial load is concerned, then you can use a different variable to loop over in your template..

```
@Component({
  template: '<p *ngFor="let character of initialCharacters">{{ character }}</p>',
})
export class TestComponent {
  public characters = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
  public initialCharacters = this.characters.slice();
}
```